# does not continue reading input from the user?

Tags: c++

When i run this program by input 50000, the output stops at 633 instead of 50000, Why and How to fix it !??

```
 int main()
{
     long int n;

     cin>>n; //n = input = 50000 

    double* r = new double[n];


    for(long int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>r[i]; // each value is in range 6 digits 
        cout<<i<<"  "<<r[i]<< endl; //i should stops at 49999
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So I'd guess you have a file containing 50000 numbers and redirected input? Or are you telling us, you want someone to input 50000 numbers by hand??

Answer (score 1):

You don't check the result of

```
cin>>r[i];
```

So it could easily happen that `cin` goes to fail state after getting an invalid input. As soon you hit this situation, no more data can be retrieved from `cin` until `cin.clear()` is called.

You should have some code like

```
if(!(cin >> r[i])) {
    cout << "Invalid input, please try again" << endl;
    --i;
    cin.clear();
}
```

to handle this.

Comment: I tried your method ,but the compiler didn't read all the input and stops at "i = 316 " an didn't continue (waiting for continuing the input)......shortly the compiler read the "50000" input number as a "316" input number, i don't know why ??